# Can't get past password screen!

Tags: 14.04

I'm running Windows Vista alongside Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.13.0-52. After upgrading my software, Unity now prompts for a password after boot even though I disabled that. My sudo password doesn't work in this field either.

Comment: What exactly happens, when you enter your password? Is it rejected immediately? Is it accepted at first, but you return to the login screen quickly thereafter? Do you use Ubuntu's default display manager LightDM? Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: When the system boots, and I enter what I thought was my old password, the system screen goes blank, but then returns with the request for a password. If I try to input some random password, it will return with a 'Invalid Password, please try again' message.  Yes

Comment: Sorry, to continue, yes, I am using the default display manager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)